# Remmina scale resolution when connect from Ubuntu to Windows 10

Tags: display-resolution, remote-desktop

When I connect from my home Ubuntu to my office PC the resolution is too great and all the fonts and other screen items are so tiny so I cannot see anything.

This is due to my new monitor at home with 4K resolution. When I connect to Windows 10 I have to choose "use client resolution option" otherwise if I choose "custom resolution" option Remmina makes screen smaller but does not change resolution.

Windows 10 does not allow to change any display setting from a remote session.

What I want to do is to make fonts, icons etc. larger on Windows 10 when I connect to it from Ubuntu 16.04 using Remmina.

Any ideas?

P.S. The left-most icon "Fit remote resolution" is disabled.

Answer (score 47):

I could simply scale by using "Toggle dynamic resolution update" menu icon in the floating tab once connected.
[image]

This fixes my issue
[remmina](/questions/tagged/remmina)[display-resolution](/questions/tagged/display-resolution)

Comment: This button is greyed out when I connect to macOS. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Same for me with a remote Debian

Comment: The button doesn't change the display scaling but the image scaling, making the text not 2x as many pixels tall but it makes everything low-res and very blurry

Comment: Thanks Dear @upHiller.

Answer (score 8):

Recent remmina versions can set RDP remote windows desktop scaling factor. From the global preferences menu -> RDP. But you need an updated remmina version and an OS (windows 8.1 or higher) that supports scaling factor. Upgrade remmina following instructions on the main website http://www.remmina.org. We provide a PPA for ubuntu 16.04.
If you already enabled local scaling on your local PC, and usually this is the case when using a 4K monitor, you should also play with the remmina scaler function to neutralize the Xorg/Unity scaling, because remmina can't currently do to it.

Comment: I had to search where that option is and it's in Preferences->RDP->Remote scale factor. I set it to 200%. My Xorg desktop is also set to 200% and it works well, so I don't know what you mean by 'neutralizing'. Also I noticed that turning on 'Dynamic resolution update' doesn't work and makes everything 4x as big, so you need to take a screenshot, paste in an image editor, measure the pixel size of the viewport that the remote computer is rendered at, and add that as a custom resolution (right-click client->Edit->Resolution)

Answer (score 4):

Better use *freerdp*.
After you installed it you use it like this from a terminal:

```
xfreerdp /u:username /p:password /w:1366 /h:768 /v:ipaddress /smart-sizing +auto-reconnect
```

The username, password, ipaddress should be the ones of the remote desktop. +auto-reconnect allows for a stable connection in a poor network.

Replace the resolution 1366 and 768 also by the resolution of the host.
The rdp window scales smoothly.

I tried several other RDP clients, but those did not work.....

Comment: Black screen for me with Linux (Ok with Remmina or rdesktop).

Answer (score 3):

You should choose "custom resolution" and then set scaling display from toolbar, as I know this is the only usable solution now

Comment: There's some advice about how to set the settings at https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/issues/1884#note_165372849 which works for me (except for the mouse cursor being too big, but that's a minor and for me acceptable problem).